# Right-Left text goof in new duplicate banner

Tags: bug, status-completed, hebrew, exact-duplicates, display

We just had [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26478/759) closed as a dupe and merged. Its dupe's title contains Hebrew lettering which seems to have thrown off the banner, as shown:
[image: Browser screenshot showing a closed-as-duplicate question, with the duplicate banner including Hebrew text from the end of the previous question's title inserted between "5" and "answers" instead of before the "5"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bad - a fix will be pushed out in the next build, > rev 2013.2.21.516.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to insert a left-to-right mark (U+200E) before `<span class="question-originals-answer-count">`. This probably should be done systemwide, not just on Mi Yodeya, because of the possibility of right-to-left characters elsewhere.

Comment: Another solution would be to set the direction of the aforementioned `span` as left-to-right using  `dir='ltr'` or CSS: but I'm *guessing* those have less browser support.

Comment: We use the `dir` attribute elsewhere; just going to add that.  Thanks!